# MySQL SUM do not return proper value, it removes decimal places. How to prevent this?

Tags: php, mysql, sum

This is very strange to me, I see it first time in my life. I do not know is this proper behavior or something is wrong. I hope some one will be able to enlighten me.

This is my simple SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/ba125/4

What I want to do is very simple. I want to sum all money for the group of energy. So there is table column called **group**. And not surprisingly it hold the names of groups that companies can belong to. Among others, there is group called "energy". There is also one more column, called "money". It holds the amount of money that each company is making over year ( profit ). I need to sum all profit ( money ) for companies belonging to "energy" group. Sounds simple, but I have a problem. In money table, money is stored as varchar in this format "1.234.567", meaning that this company have profit of 1 million 234 thousands... I am not guilty that this format is used, I am working on system made long before I started to work on it. But where is my problem ? Well, if you look at the fiddle, I am executing one simple query that is selection money for energy group:

`select money from finance where group = "energy"`

And it displays nicely how much money each company made. But if I execute this query:

`select sum(money) as total from finance where group = "energy"`

I get strange result of **99.317**, and I was hoping for **18.103.571**. What the heck is going on here ? Is there any hope for me to get right result ? Thank you

Comment: It's not really that weird, you are not doing anything to explicitly convert those chars into numbers. MySQL is probably converting the `3.607.942` to `3.607942`.

Comment: Why would you be hoping for two decimal points? That's wrong.

Comment: What kind of value is 18.103.571? Why would there be 2 decimal places?

Comment: Horrid formatting.   Use a replace function to replace '.' with ''....that will remove all those decimals.  Convert that over to a number and divide by 100 to put the decimal where it needs to be.  Might have issues with trailing 0's in doing this

Comment: @Jakobud in some countries the `.` is the thousand separator instead of `,`, so I'm guessing op is using that

Comment: Oh yeah I realize that. So the numbers the OP has in his table are not small decimal values but rather very large numbers? In that case he needs to get rid of the decimals because that is just confusing. No programming language have thousand separators in INTs and FLOATS/DOUBLES.

Comment: Yes, those numbers are big, dots are thousands separators. I am working on database that was made long ago before I started working on it, and I can not alter it now, and I do not know why people before me have chosen to use this format, I agree that it is bad :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must remove all dots from `money` column.

`REPLACE` function will resolve Your problem. But this is still not elegant solution.

[JSFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/ba125/15/0)

```
SELECT SUM(REPLACE(money,'.','')) AS `money_sum` FROM finance WHERE `group` = "energy"
```

Maybe You will think about most elegant solution? (format without dots for example).

Comment: Thank you. You gave me a solution that will solve my problem without altering database, and that is what I need at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

Don't store numbers as `varchar(n)`.  Don't insert numbers as strings.

If your numbers are forever to be integers, use `integer`. For money, you should *usually* use `decimal`. Use the number of decimal places appropriate to your currency. For me, that's 2.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `finance` (
  `id` mediumint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `money` decimal(14,2) NOT NULL,
  primary key (`id`)
); 

INSERT INTO `finance` (`group`, `money`) VALUES
('energy',     3543),
('other',     19881),
('other',     13536),
('other',        20),
('energy',  3607942),
('energy',    66768),
('energy',    10985),
('other',      2150),
('energy', 14414333);  

select sum(money) 
from finance 
where `group` = 'energy';   -- 18103571.00
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am sure that this is a proper way of doing it. But because I can not alter database and need to work with what I got, I will have to chose answer that is solving my problem without altering DB.

Comment: Find out who *can* alter the table. Have them run this INSERT statement:  ``insert into `finance` (`group`, `money`) values ('energy', 'BROKEN!');``.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are storing integer values as `varchar`. That problem is compounded when you start using a decimal as a thousands separator like many countries and locales do because MySQL makes some assumptions when it automatically casts the varchar's as floats.

1. Store the numbers as INT.
2. Get rid of your thousand separators in your input. Normalize it. Store the data only as INTs without any decimals or commas. This will guarantee proper arithmetic operations.
3. Format your thousands separator after the fact:

   ```
   select REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(FORMAT(SUM(MONEY),0), ',', '~'), '.', ','),'~', '.') AS format from finance where `group` = "energy"
   ```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/4214b/8